# Facing error when uploading file given in a coursera course

Tags: file-upload, error-handling, google-bigquery, create-table

I am in the middle of a course in coursera (Google Data Analytics)titled: "process Data from Dirty to Clean". In this course's 3rd module they gave a CSV file to upload in BigQuery to create a Table but when I uploaded the file a massage popup that says "CSV processing encountered too many errors". I didn't change or modify or did  anything with that file but it's not working.

I followed the instruction step by step given in the course several time and expecting to create a Table  in BigQuery with that file.
I am uploading as csv files,  edit as text.

Comment: Are specifying to skip the header row?

Answer (score 0):

When you download the data, the best way is to download it as a workbook. When you force it to be a `csv` then it looks like this
[image: Downloading the work book as a csv].

What I did was to download it as an Excel document and then upload it to Google Sheets before downloading it as a CSV (Google Sheets has that option). [image: Data in google sheets]

Now you can load your data from Google Sheets or download a CSV and upload it to BQ. I am feeling a bit lazy to code but you could also open the Excel file in `Python` for example and save it as a `csv` or save it directly to `BQ` using `pandas_gbq`.

Final output.[image]

Comment: Here is the link of the data,                                                    
 https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ahq8H4GaPS-cjQdLIszRRbXgsZ2n?e=t0HE0Y

Comment: The problem is that when you download the data from one drive its a workbook and not a CSV. I will edit my solution to show you how I solved this.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your effort.  I might not described my problem correctly, I m really sorry for that.   When I was creating table In BigQuery If I select "Auto detect Schema" than it creates the table perfectly but when I was trying "edit as text" the schemas then this problem is happening. I mentioned this earlier but might not described correctly.   Thank You again for your solution, I m sure It will help me in future.